# Arrange all columns in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data

```
library(dplyr)
a <- c(4,5,2,1,3,1,2,2)
b <- c(1,0.5,20,15,13,0.2,8,2)
c <- c(3,4,1,2,0.3,11,12,13)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I want to arrange the data according to all columns

```
df <- df %>% arrange(a,b,c)
```

But instead of typing all column names, I want to pass all columns at once without typing each name.

Comment: Base R : `df[do.call(order, df), ]`

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for :

```
df %>% arrange_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, here's a couple:

```
# 1)
df[,order(colnames(df))]

# 2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(order(colnames(.)))
```

Both print

```
  a    b    c
1 4  1.0  3.0
2 5  0.5  4.0
3 2 20.0  1.0
4 1 15.0  2.0
5 3 13.0  0.3
6 1  0.2 11.0
7 2  8.0 12.0
8 2  2.0 13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

From `dplyr` version `1.0.0` you can avaid arrange_all, _at, _if with `across` and `everything` for selecting all columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(4,5,2,1,3,1,2,2)
b <- c(1,0.5,20,15,13,0.2,8,2)
c <- c(3,4,1,2,0.3,11,12,13)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)

df %>% 
  arrange(across(everything()))
#>   a    b    c
#> 1 1  0.2 11.0
#> 2 1 15.0  2.0
#> 3 2  2.0 13.0
#> 4 2  8.0 12.0
#> 5 2 20.0  1.0
#> 6 3 13.0  0.3
#> 7 4  1.0  3.0
#> 8 5  0.5  4.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>